# Industrial IoT remote connectivity

Tags: industry-4.0

We are robotics based company.We started our work in Industrial IoT, as we are in early stage.The problem we are facing is remote connectivity between server client.

The server which has static IP is connected to main office. The client is connected to a robot with m2m 3G router via Ethernet access. Both the connections are at different network.I want to know the best possible solution.

Comment: Welcome to IoT.SE! Please elaborate a bit more. Such as: (1) The client a hardware or a software module installed on the robot? (2) If client I hardware module, is client IP capable or using a bus protocol to communicate with the robot? The setup is not very clear from the question, a diagram may be more helpful.

Comment: OK, you have a server, a "main office", a client, a robot, and a router. We now a little bit about connections, however it is not clear what you mean with "both the connections are on different networks" (probably you mean that the addresses if the corresponding endpoints belong to the same network). Then I guess that the network the robot belongs to requires the highest access privileges.

Comment: Best possible solution! This is to ask for opinions and that is discouraged by SE. Please clarify if "Static IP" is a public internet IP. And to use IP is something I would avoid, a FQDN is preferable since IP can change and then it is easy to change that in the DNS server zone file.

Comment: Welcome, Rohan. I'm afraid you'll need to specify more information as sob indicates to get a good answer here. I'm putting this on hold to give you opportunity to [edit] with clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I work as a solution engineer at Talend, and I’ve worked on IOT / SCADA integration. While you’ve not supplied much detail, to me this sounds like a data integration problem.

If that’s the right problem, then your choices are to build or buy an IOT platform solution. An IOT platform covers ingest from various IOT sources, processing, analytics, and publish to various target systems. https://www.talend.com/blog/2017/04/11/simplify-iot-platform-talend/

Here’s more on how Talend’s Data Fabric works for IOT...

> Talend brings it all together in an end-to-end integration platform that combines IoT connectivity (AMQP, MQTT); high-speed, reliable messaging (Apache Kafka, Amazon Kinesis, Talend ESB); and high-speed big data processing (Apache Spark).

https://www.talend.com/solutions/information-technology/internet-of-things-real-time/